# Logstash alternative for elasticsearch on java 6

Tags: elasticsearch, log4j, logstash

I need to send logs from log4j to elastisearch. But all frameworks I found require java 7. My system works on java 6 and upgrading java is not an option.
Do you know any alternate ways to interface log4j with elasticsearch?

Comment: How about beaver?  https://github.com/josegonzalez/python-beaver

Comment: do you want to ship text files? or can you ship from an application directly to elasticsearch?

Comment: actually i solved it by using socketAppender which sends logs to server with elasticsearch.Java 7 is installed there so logstash works well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be useful for somebody:

On machine with my application with java 6 I created asyncAppender with socketAppender:

```
<appender name="Async" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
 <param name="Blocking" value="true" />
 <appender-ref ref="Elastic" />
</appender>

<appender name="Elastic" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender">  
 <param name="Port" value="4712" />  
 <param name="RemoteHost" value="server_IP" />  
 <param name="ReconnectionDelay" value="60000" />  
 <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR" />  
 <layout class="net.logstash.log4j.JSONEventLayoutV0"/>
</appender>
```

Then, on machine with java 7 i started simpleSocketServer with properties saved in log4j-server.properties file:

```
#Define a narrow log category. A category like debug will produce some extra logs also from server itself
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, file

#Define how the socket server should store the log events
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=application-error.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=net.logstash.log4j.JSONEventLayoutV0
```

To start simpleSocketServer you need eg. apache-log4j-1.2.17
then you run it from command line:

```
java -classpath "log4j-1.2.17.jar:lib/*" org.apache.log4j.net.SimpleSocketServer 4712 log4j-server.properties
```

In lib folder i added jsonevent-layout-1.7.jar so i can use net.logstash.log4j.JSONEventLayoutV0

With this configuration my logs are saved in log4j-1.2.17/application-error.log from where my logstash reads it.